# Creating formula based on binary tree leaves

Tags: python, data-structures, numpy, binary-tree, lis

I have list of points with length n (in below example n = 6) after that I have made some other points based on these default point for example point 7 are made by "anding" point 5 and point 4 and so on now my question is based on the data structure I have, how can I retrieve the chain of formula? for example for the point 10 (recursive or non recursive) how can I say from where this point is coming?.

If I want to know how point 10 is made it must return something like this:

```
(((5 & 4) | 3) | 2) & (5 & 4)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you already have some data structures for representing what you've got?

Comment: @Alfe no I have just made an example, right now I just have the list point + list of new point (in one list) and 3 different list which keep the first point and second point and operator

Comment: I suggest to transform what you've got into a value which can be kept in one variable instead.  See my answer as an explanation for what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a representation of what you've got before you start.  I suggest sth like this:

```
points = [ None,  # dummy value to fill index 0 (we want to start at 1)
           None, None, None, None, None, None,  # for the first six atoms
           (5, 4, '&'),  # for point 7
           (7, 3, '|'),  # for point 8
           (8, 2, '|'),  # for point 9
           (9, 7, '&') ]  # for point 10
```

Then creating a formula as a string is just recursive:

```
def formula(points, n):
  if points[n] is None:
    return str(n)
  a, b, operator = points[n]
  return '(%s %s %s)' % (formula(points, a), operator, formula(points, b))

print formula(points, 10)
```

This will print

```
((((5 & 4) | 3) | 2) & (5 & 4))
```

To get all points used in a formula as a set, just use this:

```
def used(points, n):
  if points[n] is None:
    return { n }
  a, b, operator = points[n]
  return used(points, a) | used(points, b)

print used(points, 10)
```

will print:

```
set([2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: I will try to do as you suggest but one quick question in your solution is it necessary to start at index 1?

Comment: and my second question how can I get only all unique point? for example in above example just a list contains [2,3,4,5], thanks in advance

Comment: Of course not.  I just adjusted to what you've got in your question.  _You_ start with index 1 :)

Comment: What makes a point unique?  What the definition?  Do you want a list of all _used_ points in that formula?

Comment: Yes I want list of all used points in that formula :) Thank you for your help

Comment: Added a part for the points in use by a formula.  But remember, SO is not a platform for letting other people code your stuff ;-)  You already extended your original question by a new one.  This was a cinch, so I didn't mind adding that, but you should consider asking _new_ questions for new features of your code which you have trouble writing yourself.  And, again, try something before asking here :)